# Ruby on Rails undefined method `session' for # OrderNotifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm developing a online store site following Agile Web Development with Rails 4 book and I'm new to rails.

Here's my _line_item.html.erb template rendered as a cart in the sidebar.

```
<% if line_item == @current_item %>
    <tr id="current_item">
<% else %>
    <tr>
<% end %>
        <td><%= line_item.quantity %>&times;</td>
        <td><%= line_item.product.title %></td>
        <td class="line_item_price" align="right">
            <%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price) %>
        </td>
        <% if !session[:cart_id].nil? %>
            <td><%= button_to "X", line_item, method: :delete, remote: true, 
                                        :disabled => !@order.nil? %></td>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
```

So, when used as a siderbar, it works perfectly fine. But I also want to use the template for the confirmation email but obviously I don't want those X buttons to appear there, so I added an if condition outside the button_to helper. I thought it could be working because in my orders_controller.rb,

```
    ......
def create
@order = Order.new(order_params)
@order.add_line_items_from_cart(@cart)

*LINE38* respond_to do |format|
           if @order.save
             Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
             session[:cart_id] = nil
    *LINE42* OrderNotifier.received(@order).deliver
     ......
```

I set session[:cart_id] to nil if the create action was successful. If I don't use _line_item.html.erb as the template everything works fine, the order's created and the email is sent because there's no button issues. But if I do, after I trigger the create action from orders_controller.rb, the browser says "**undefined method `session' for # OrderNotifier:0x007ffd207bc800>**".

So here's my question, if the method or whatever is undefined, isn't it nil? What is the underlying problem here and how do I fix it the way I expected?

You can go to http://online-bookstore.herokuapp.com/ for a closer view of the site but FYI the email sending part wasn't deployed there so when it says "thanks for the order" it doesn't send the email.

Here's my order_notifier.rb in mailers/

```
......
def received(order)
  @order = order

  *LINE23* mail to: order.email, subject: 'Your Order Confirmation'
end
......
```

And the error messages:

```
Showing /home/jeremy/online-store/app/views/line_items/_line_item.html.erb where line #9 raised:

undefined method 'session' for #<OrderNotifier:0x007ff296453108>
Extracted source (around line #9):

        <td><%= line_item.quantity %>&times;</td>
        <td><%= line_item.product.title %></td>
        <td class="line_item_price" align="right"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price) %></td>
  *LINE9* <% if !session[:cart_id].nil? %>
        <td><%= button_to "X", line_item, method: :delete, remote: true, 
                                            :disabled => !@order.nil? %></td>
        <% end %>

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/order_notifier/received.html.erb

Rails.root: /home/jeremy/online-store

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/line_items/_line_item.html.erb:9:in '_app_views_line_items__line_item_html_erb___1832667105729053783_70339760911020'
app/views/order_notifier/received.html.erb:8:in '_app_views_order_notifier_received_html_erb__517934132095274867_70339761303220'
app/mailers/order_notifier.rb:23:in 'received'
app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:42:in 'block in create'
app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:38:in 'create'
```

**Thanks so much for the help!!**

Comment: Form the error message it looks like the problem is not in this controller, but in your `OrderNotifier`. Can you please also post your `OrderNotifier`? Furthermore error messages usually include a file name and a line number. You may want to post the message to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `session` within your `OrderNotifer` class. `session` is only available in context of controllers and views. But you can pass that `session` to your `Mailer` and make it available there.

```
# change the line in your controller where you create you Mailer
OrderNotifier.received(@order, session).deliver

# change order_notifier.rb
def received(order, session)
  @order   = order
  @session = session
  ...

# change to line that currently raises the exception to
<% if @session[:cart_id] %>
```

This makes the whole `session` object as `@session` available in your mailer and mailer views. This is not best practice, but should immediately solve your problem.

If your just need the `card_id` in your view, than it is better to just pass that value to your view:

```
# in controller
OrderNotifier.received(@order, session[:card_id]).deliver

# in mailer
def received(order, card_id)
  @order   = order
  @card_id = card_id
  ...

# in mailer view
<% if @cart_id %>
```

Comment: The first solution didn't work, as I refreshed the home page it complained undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass at <% if @session[:cart_id] %>. As a newbie, I am guessing the session variable can't just be passed this way, correct? And the second one did work!! And then it came to me that the simpliest solution should be changing "if !session[:cart_id].nil?" to "if @cart" and that's it, since we are gonna destroy the current cart before we execute the received() method. But still, thanks a lot!